# Function pointer to boost::geometry function

Tags: c++, function-pointers, boost-geometry

I'm trying to pass the `boost::geometry::get` function [described here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/access/get/get_2.html) to another function, but I can't seem to get it right.

I have:

```
template<typename StorageType = double,
         std::size_t D = 3>
class Derivative : public DerivativeBase<StorageType, D> {
public:
typedef typename DerivativeBase<StorageType, D>::results_t results_t;

template<typename Iterator, typename Geometry>
results_t operator()(Iterator& objIterator, StorageType (*getter)(Geometry const&))
...
```

and the compiler throws:

```
error: no match for call to ‘(Derivative<double, 3ul>) (iterator&, <unresolved overloaded function type>)’
```

I tried calling my function with:

```
derivs = myDerivs(it, &boost::geometry::get<0>);
```

I guess part of the issue is that since I don't pass an argument to `get`, the compiler can't figure out what type `Geometry` should be in the function signature.

How do I go about passing this function through?

Comment: You might want to remove all the unnecessary surroundings and reduce this to a simple `std::get` which have all the same issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is entirely non-specific to `boost.geometry`. You need to `static_cast` the function to it's exact type if it is overloaded or you need to pass all template parameters explicitly. The second is the case here (e.g. `&get<0, GeometryType>`).

Comment: Providing the type to the template for `get` doesn't seem to help any. I'll see if I can boil it down to a non-boost example.

Comment: It turns out that the problem I was having actually is due to the `boost::geometry` and the `get` function having default, undocumented parameters. Without specifying them in the function pointer declaration, it didn't matter that I had the template arguments because it didn't match anyway.

Comment: @tpg2114 In that case I would suggest using a C++11 lambda or wrap the call to get into a functor. That way you don't have to specify the arguments, just the name of the functor and the call to `operator()` will use template parameter deduction. function templates with default parameters, non-argument parameters etc. are a bitch to bind.